# How to restrict data by users in Google Data Studio?

Tags: looker-studio

I have a report in google data studio and needed to restrict information by branches at user level. For example: In the same sales report, branch A users cannot see branch B data.

Is it possible in Google Data Studio?

Answer (score 2):

unfortunately this feature is not available for a single data studio report. You will have to create branch specific reports and give access to the correct users to accomplish your goal.

Answer (score 0):

you can use URL parameters and build the report so it will show the relevant parts per the parameters you pass.
https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9002005?hl=en